# How to convert month name array to number array

Tags: php

Here i have defined my month name array

```
$months = array(1 => 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
```

Below is the code i loop throgh it for getting the month names in a dropdown.

```
<tr>
    <td>Period From:<span id="star">*</span> 

        <select name="monthfrom" id="monthfrom" style="width:60px">
            <option value="Month">Month</option>
            <?php
            foreach ($months as $value) {
                echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>\n';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

After excuting i want month names in the dropdown but value should be a two-digit month number (with leading zeroes).

Comment: you can print array_keys

Comment: go look at the foreach() documentation the answer is in there. or let the users below spoon feed the answer so you will never learn

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($months as $key=>$value) {
    printf('<option value="%02d">%s</option>', $key, $value);
}
```

Comment: I want the month names in 01,02 like format.But it is coming in 1,2 like format.

Comment: @user1033199 You should specify that in your question. In any case `printf('<option value="%02d">%s</option>', $key, $value)`

Comment: I modified for two-digit months.

Comment: @JonHulka `printf` is better

Comment: @Phil is it more efficient?

Comment: @JonHulka Not that this sort of micro-optimisation matters but yes, it is significantly more efficient

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `$key=>$value`, you can also use a counter for determining the numerical value of the corresponding month:

```
$x = 1;

foreach ($months as $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $x . '">' . $value . '</option>\n';
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: The values are all separate. The `1 => 'Jan'` just seems to seed the numeric array indexes at `1` instead of `0` (neat trick by the way)

Comment: Just caught that after second glance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreeach like

```
  foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
     statement
```

[from manual foreach ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#control-structures.foreach)

so now you can do  this by

```
foreach ($months as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you. Try this,

```
$months = array('1' => 'Jan', '2'=>'Feb', '3'=>'Mar', '4'=>'Apr', '5'=>'May', '6'=>'Jun', '7'=>'Jul', '8'=>'Aug', '9'=>'Sep', '10'=>'Oct', '11'=>'Nov', '12'=>'Dec');
```

And your select box should be,

```
<select name="monthfrom" id="monthfrom" style="width:60px">
                        <option value="Month">Month</option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($months as $key=> $value) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>\n';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
```