# Convert days to two digits format

Tags: php

Below i have defined the day range

```
$days = range(1, 31);
```

How can we loop through using this range to get the values of days in 01,02,03 like format in a dropdown list

Tried this

```
foreach ($days as $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>\n';
}
```

Comment: <?php
                            foreach ($days as $value) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>\n';
                            }
                            ?>

Comment: This was already answered in your other question - [How to convert month name array to number array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516650/how-to-convert-month-name-array-to-number-array). Voting to close

Answer (score 9):

```
$days = array_map(function($val) {
  return sprintf('%02d', $val);
}, range(1, 31));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
<?php
$arr = "0";
for ($arr = 0; $arr < 32; $arr++) {
    if ($arr < 10) {
        $arr = "0" . $arr;
    }
    echo $arr . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_day()
{
    $days = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
    {
        if(strlen($i) == 1)
        { 
            $i = '0' . $i; 
        }
        $days[$i] = $i;
    }
    return $days;
}

$days = get_day();

foreach($days as $day)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<select>";
for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++) {
    echo "<option>".str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```