# Replace PHP array value with current day

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$flights = Array (
   [0] => Array (
      [day] => 0
      [flights] => 0
   )
   [1] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [2] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [3] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [4] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [5] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [6] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [7] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [8] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   ) 
   [9] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   ) 
   [10] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   ) 
   [11] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   ) 
   [12] => Array ( 
      [day] => 0 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
)
```

And I want to replace all `[day]` values with the current correspondent day, like:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array (
      [day] => 01
      [flights] => 0
   )
   [1] => Array ( 
      [day] => 02 
      [flights] => 0 
   )
   [2] => Array ( 
      [day] => 03
      [flights] => 0
   )
...
```

The code is creating the array key numbers according to the current day of the month, so the array has the correct number of keys for today (13/01).

What is the function to do this?

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the array and update it? Please do some more research and make some attempt yourself first. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues you might run into with your implementation attempt, but we're not here to write all your code for you (which a proper answer here would require us to)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516914/convert-days-to-two-digits-format)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some deeper search I managed to solve it with this:

```
$day_counter = 1;
foreach ($flights as $key => $value)
{
  $flights[$key]['day'] = $day_counter;
  $day_counter++;
}
```

So I start with day "1" as `$day_counter` and increment after replacing it in array.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to do:

```php
foreach ($flights as $key => $_) {
    $flights[$key]['day'] = $key + 1;
}
```

Here we're looping through all the flights, utilizing its numbered `$key`, incrementing it by `1` and assigning it to the appropriate place.

Comment: You should consider explain your solution, not just place code

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to write `$k + 1` instead of `++$k`? The increment of `$k` doesn't seem to have any purpose